# In the field $No$ of surreal numbers, does $\underbrace {\frac 1 \omega + \frac 1 \omega + ...}_{\omega\text{ times}}= 1?$

Tags: probability, surreal-numbers

The question is in the title.  It is known that $\omega$ $\cdot$ $\frac 1 {\omega}$ = 1, but can the expression on the left-hand side be replaced by the infinite sum in the title?  If so then by the fact that $No$ is a field suggests that $\frac 1 {\omega}$ can be thought of as a probability measure.  On the other hand, consider the following examples given by Prof. Conway (onpp.43-44 of *On Numbers and Games*:

> It is interesting to note that our definitions of infinite sums have in a certain sense to be "global", rather than as limits of partial sums, because limits don't seem to work. For instance, the limit of the sequence 0, $\frac 1 2$, $\frac 2 3$, $\frac 3 4$,... ($\omega$ terms) is not 1, at least in the ordinary sense, because there are plenty of numbers in between.  A simpler, but sometimes less convincing, example of the same phenomenon is given by the sequence
>
> 0,1,2,3,...
>
> of all finite ordinals, which one would expect to tend to $\omega$, but obviously can't, since there is a whole Host of numbers greater than every finite integer but less than $\omega [here Prof. Conway gives us his favorites of such numbers--my comment].

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, whoever you are....!

Comment: I don't see how Conway's statements are in any way contrary to what you have stated, assuming a total of $\omega$ terms (though one has to be very specific about the number of terms, here - to see why see my paper "Hyperreal Numbers for Infinite Divergent Series").

Comment: 1. An infinite sum is only defined with a definition of limit in the field you're working with, and I'm not greatly familiar, but I believe there are multiple notions for surreals. In the most obvious, there are in fact no limits since no countable set can enter every interval around a surreal. This goes for set-sized nets as well. I suppose you could take the minima of the sequence going forward as lower set and maxima as upper set, but then every sequence would have a limit.

Comment: 2. Since I assume this is why you're asking, we've all been there, and you're just not going to get a perfectly intuitive theory of continuous probability by any means, including non-standard analysis.

Comment: What definition of infinite sum of surreals are you using?

Comment: @johnnyb:  Thanks for the reference--very helpful.

Comment: @EricWofsey:  How many definitions of infinite sums of surreals are there anyway?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin:  The point here is that there is no definition of infinite sums that results simply from defining the surreal numbers as [a field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)).  The standard way of defining an infinite sum of (say) real numbers requires the notion of limit, which in turn depends on the standard metric topology of the real numbers.  So we are putting the burden on you, the poser of the Question, to give a definition.  Perhaps you are interested in why the definition for infinite sums of real numbers does not immediately carry over to surreal numbers?

Comment: @hardmath:  Yes, I would definitely be interested in an answer to the question posed in your comment above.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin:  See the section [Gaps and Continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number#Gaps_and_continuity) of the Wikipedia page on surreal numbers, with its link to an arXiv article "Analysis on Surreal Numbers" by Rubinstein-Salzedo and Swaminathan, published in Journal of Logic and Analysis, Volume 6, Number 5, pp. 1--39, 2014. "In this paper,
using a new representation of surreals, we obtain a formula for the limit of a surreal sequence."

Comment: At a glance my sense is that the limit of your sequence (series) of length $\omega$ gets defined in the completion $\mathbf{On}$ of the surreal numbers $\mathbf{No}$.

Comment: In what respect (if any) are the infinite surreals ( $\omega$, for instance) like nonstandard integers?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be claiming that there is an obviously-natural definition of infinite sums of surreals that should be applied to make sense of $\dfrac{1}{\omega}+\dfrac{1}{\omega}+\cdots$. But:

1. The definition of "more general infinite sums" given at the top of page 40 of On Numbers and Games (ONAG) cannot apply because for the relevant $y$, we would have $\sum_nr_{n,y}=\sum1$ which does not converge.
2. The point of the section you quote is basically "there isn't a natural definition of limit to use here", so it's not clear there's a definition of limit you can lean on to avoid the problem in #1.

But if it helps, we can note that $1$ is the simplest number greater than each of $\dfrac{n}{\omega}$ for naturals $n$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert on Surreals, but here's an argument that the answer is no.

The claim seems to be equivalent to
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac k\omega=1.$$
But for any $k\in{\mathbb N}$ and $n\in{\mathbb N}$,
$$\frac k\omega<\frac1n.$$
Since $k$ is arbitrary, it would seem that under any reasonable definition of limit
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac k\omega\leq \frac1n.$$
And then since $n$ is arbitrary, this means that the limit is an infinitesimal.

I believe this was essentially Cantor's argument against infinitesimals: even an infinite sum of them is still infinitesimal.

A possible escape might be an alternate definition of the sum of an infinite series that is different from the limit.  Another possibility might be somehow distinguishing between $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}$ and $\lim_{k\rightarrow\omega^-}$.

Related question: is
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1=\omega?$$
Probably not, for a similar reason.  I think it would be the smallest possible infinite value, which is not $\omega$ in view of $\omega-1$, $\omega-2$, etc.

This all goes along with an opinion I saw in another thread: Surreals don't cooperate well with analysis.